# substitute 22AWG 8 strand solid copper for Cat5?

Tags: audio

My 1995 house is wired for a whole house audio system with 22AWG 8 strand solid copper CL2 wire to all of the control keypads.  All of the new replacement audio equipment requires Cat5 to the keypads.  It would be very difficult to re-wire. Can I use my existing wiring as a substitute for Cat5?  Is there a wiring color conversion chart?

Comment: Wire is, just wire - copper. Unless you need shielding from cross talks, etc.

Comment: That said, you cannot use a single wire as a substitute for 8-wire UTP.

Comment: Of course I meant 8 wires AWG in place of 8 wires in a Cat5

Comment: This depends entirely on what protocol is running over the wire and how long it is. If it's ethernet to the new keypads, I'd not expect it to work on long runs. Maybe a manufacturer/model for the new keypads would help?

Comment: Longest run is about 150 feet.  Only signals to control volume and source are being sent.  No video transmission

Comment: I can use a variety of keypads.  One is Elan Z200.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, whether or not substituting one wire type for another will work generally depends on the protocol that is used over the wires. CAT5 cable is designed the way it is to minimize cross-talk and interference while using the Ethernet protocol.

That being said, I believe that you would be just fine making this substitution. Here's why:

1. According to the ANSI standard, solid core CAT5 cable must be between AWG22 and AWG24. Since your wire meets this standard, I think it's safe to assume you won't burn anything out from trying to drive too much current over a wire. The product designers probably assumed everyone would use twisted-pair CAT5, but solid core does exist, and your wire meets the standard.
2. If we run with your Elan Z200 example, we can take a look at the user manual ([pdf link](http://www.elanportal.com/supportdocs/catalog/z-im-z200.pdf)). On page 4 (PDF page 5), we see that according to their pinout, they aren't actually using the Ethernet protocol:
   [image: E-Z200 Wiring Diagram]

   In fact, most of them aren't even connected. It looks to me like the just decided to use a common connector (RJ45) and common wiring standard (CAT5) for their product to make things cheaper and easier for the end user. Since they aren't using Ethernet, you should be alright. One caveat though, is that I don't see anything that specifies what communication protocol the "IR Distribution" is using. It's probably okay since protocols like I2C and serial communication run at speeds much lower than Ethernet, so interference will likely be minimal.
3. The manual specifies a maximum run distance of 500 feet, and your maximum run of 150 feet is obviously well below that.

Overall, I don't see any reason your wire shouldn't work. It doesn't look like the device uses any kind of high-frequency communication protocol that would be susceptible to interference, and your wire meets the CAT5 standard for thickness (and thus current-carrying ability), so I don't see a fire hazard.

Comment: "IR" makes me think that it's that 38kHz IR protocol commonly used by IR remotes et alia.

Comment: 38kHz IR "protocol" refers to the IR wave itself. This is very clearly a wired connection. I think it connects the wall control panel with an IR receiver/transmitter somewhere else that would use something like the 38kHz standard to communicate with a remote, but that has nothing to do with the communications taking place over the wires.

Comment: This wouldn't be the first time that a wireless encoding was used on a wire.

Comment: It's also worth noting that ethernet works the way it works because it's *differential*, and that pinout is not using the differential twisted pairs in a differential manner.

Comment: While the conclusion may be true, the idea implicit here that "solid core" and "twisted pair" are alternatives is severely mistaken.  Either solid or stranded conductors may be twisted into pairs at a controlled number of twists per unit length, or run in parallel or with minimal / uncontrolled twisting.  Typically, infrastructure runs of cat 5 are solid and patch cords stranded.